# Background color for complete table

Tags: tables, color

I would like to have an entire table (including the caption) with a background color. I already found solution for cells and rows (which also did not work perfectly), but not for the whole table.

Can I build an whole environment around it? If yes, how?

Thank you very much in advance

Paul

Comment: Please give the code you've already written. This will serve as a starting point for users wishing to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simply `\colorbox{`*your color*`}{`*your table*`}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Foo}\centering 
\colorbox{green!20}{\begin{tabular}{cc}
foo & baz\\
\midrule
11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It could look better with some settings before of the table (but inside the float if you want limit the setting to this table only). For instance:

```
\setlength\fboxsep{1ex}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1ex}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: How do you get the caption into the green area with this solution?

Comment: Put the caption and the tabular inside a minipage (some like ` \begin{minipage}{7em} ...
\end{minipage}`. Then apply the colorbox to the minipage instead that to the tabular environment only.

Comment: \begin{minipage}{7em} 
\colorbox{green!20}{
\begin{table}
\caption{Foo}\centering \begin{tabular}{cc}
foo & baz\\
\midrule
11 & 12 \\
13 & 14 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}
\end{minipage} , does not work for me :-(

Comment: @user34047 No, no, no ... the tabular environment and the caption inside the minipage, the minipage inside the color box, the color box inside the table. The table environment is a float and this mean that it cannot be inside anything (except the `document` environment, of course).

Comment: Thx a lot. Now it works

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE based on `tcolorbox` might serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=tables]{mytable}[2][]{float=htb, 
                                               halign=center,  
                                               title={#2}, 
                                               every float=\centering, 
                                               sharp corners,
                                               coltitle=black,
                                               colback=yellow,
                                               colbacktitle=yellow,
                                               boxrule=0pt,
                                               frame hidden,
                                               #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}[float=t, label=mykey]{This is a floating box}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
column header 1 & column header 2\\
\midrule
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{mytable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much leandriis! One quick follow ups: 1) How can I get the caption/title to the bottom?

Comment: By the way: Would "\newtcolorbox[blend into=tikzfigures]{mytikzfig}[2][]{float=htb, 
       halign=center,    title={#2}, every float=\centering, sharp corners,  coltitle=black, colback=yellow, colbacktitle=yellow, boxrule=0pt,                           frame hidden,  #1}"  work the same way?

Comment: Regarding your second question: According to the manual, you can only choose from `tables`, `figures` or `listings` for `blend into=`.